# Trying to understand this async await conundrum

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a specific example of async await with a problem that I can't wrap my head around.

```
 public async Task<bool> DoStuff()
 {
    //do some stuff
    return await DoSomeOtherStuff();
 }

 public Task<bool> SomeOtherMethod()
 {
     return DoStuff();
 }

 public bool SomeSynchronousMethod()
 {
    //this method does a lot of stuff, but most importantly, it calls SomeOtherMethod without awaiting it

    SomeOtherMethod();

    /// some more stuff

    //imagine DoStuff sends an e-mail. Sometimes the e-mail will be sent without problem, sometimes it won't be.

    return true;
 }
```

The method `DoStuff()` awaits an async task. The method `SomeOtherMethod` doesn't always work if I do **not** await the result. In my mind, I thought if the method `DoStuff()` awaits the result, I will always receive a valid result, even if I don't await my `SomeOtherMethod()` result, but it does not seem to work like that.

(I am sure, because adding the extra await whenever I call `SomeOtherMethod` actually solved a pretty weird bug).

Is this right in what I'm seeing? What concept am I missing that would explain why this does not work as I would have expected?

Comment: See [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) by the great Stephen C - I think it's for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't always work"? `SomeOtherMethod` should be just fine -- adding an addition async/await will add some overhead, but won't change anything functionally (it'll change how exceptions get handled, but your example doesn't throw any)

Comment: Without knowledge about actual implementation of `DoSomeOtherStuff`,  `DoStuff` and `SomeOtherMethod` it is hard to tell what is the bug and reason for it. Provided code should work just fine. Recommended reading - [eliding async-await by Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Comment: Actually added another method to showcase what I mean. `SomeSynchronousMethod` calls the `SomeOtherMethod()` without awaiting the result. 

This doesn't seem to be reliable. Or the problem is elsewhere entirely of course, but the problem did seem to go away after I have added an await to my synchronous method (which I obviously made asynchronous too).

Comment: What is the type of the application that demonstrates this behavior? Is it [ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)?

Comment: Unless you await `SomeOtherMethod()` the execution of `SomSynchronousMethod()` will continue and the method will complete before `SomeOtherMethod()` had a chance to complete. The entire object may get disposed before `SomeOtherMethod` had a chance to complete. Don't use such code. At the very least you'd have to `.Wait()` the task returned by `SomeOtherMethod`

Comment: BTW it doesn't matter what type of application this is. If you had a desktop or console application, created an object that calls `SomeSynchronousMethod` and disposed it when that method finished,  `SomeOtherMethod` would still be orphaned. If it tried eg to access a connection in the disposed object it would still throw

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis, I had begun to expect the same.

Comment: In short, the problem isn't caused by `async/await`. It's because `SomeOtherMethod` is not awaited. It's like calling `Thread.Start` but never waiting for that thread to complete before trying to use the results it produces

Comment: @StevenLemmens the problem is that you are not awaiting method. The "fix" by adding `await` to `DoStuff` call is not reliable and random.

Answer (score 0):

> In my mind, I thought if the method DoStuff() awaits the result, I will always receive a valid result, even if I don't await my SomeOtherMethod() result, but it does not seem to work like that.

That's an incorrect understanding. `DoStuff()` might return immediately to the calling method, but *the `Task` it returns is guaranteed not to complete* until the Task returned from `DoSomeOtherStuff` completes. If the task returned from `DoStuff()` is not awaited, execution will continue without waiting for that Task to complete.

You haven't provided many details about the environment you're running in, but let's imagine `SomeSynchronousMethod` gets executed by a command line application, which then exits. If you don't await the task, then the application may exit before the asynchronous work happening in `DoSomeOtherStuff` is able to complete. So, for example, an HTTP or SMTP communication that's still in progress will suddenly stop and won't complete.

There are a lot of nitty-gritty details about how async/await and Tasks work: more than I can address in a StackOverflow answer. But the key principle that emerges from those details is that you should *never let a Task go unawaited*. If you want certain tasks to be accomplished in the background, but guarantee that they get completed before the app exits, you could add them to a collection and then have the application's main method await all those tasks before it exits. Different types of applications have different patterns for implementing background tasks like this.